# Блок с рекламой в приложении libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

Когда я пытался подключить рекламу в рабочем приложении через сервис appodeal возникла проблемка 
`com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536`
исходя из того что прочитал - это ошибка переполнения методов. Появляются мысли,что я где-то допускаю фатальную ошибку при коддинге. Фиксится когда я убираю библиотеку с рекламой. В результате чего могла бы эта ошибка появиться и как с ней бороться, что стоит почитать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

День добрый. Я Александр из техподдержки Appodeal.
Совершенно верно, это ошибка с превышением лимита по количеству методов. Это не ваша фатальная ошибка, просто при использовании большого количества библиотек эта проблема рано или поздно появляется.
Самая большая библиотека среди наших требований - google play services. Если вы используете Android Studio, вы можете подключить не все сервисы, а только нужные (для работы Appodeal требуется только google-play-services-ads). Обычно это изменение приводит к удачной сборке проекта.
Если же вы работаете в другой IDE, то свяжитесь с нами (знак "?" в правом нижнем углу на нашем сайте, может ошибочно блокироваться рекламными блокировщиками), мы в индивидуальном порядке решим, какие из сетей лучше всего отключить, чтобы это минимально повлияло на вашу конечную прибыль.

Comment: Блин, вы что на HellowWorld рассчитывали свое апи? Я у себя все библиотеки поотрубал, и часть ваших также - все равно DexIndexOverflowException! Да у меня без вашего монстра GameAnalytics, Flurry, Applovin, Chartboost, Mixpanel и другие уживаются, как заменил все свои на ваш пак - превышение. Вторая попытка подключить ваш апи, и опять фейл. Нет, реально, вы на кого эту хреновину рассчитывали?